# How to call EventWaitHandle.OpenExisting(String, EventWaitHandleRights) in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core

In .NET Framework, `EventWaitHandle.OpenExisting()` has two overloads: 
one that takes EventWaitHandleRights so you can specify what rights you need, and one that doesn't.

In .NET Core the one that takes EventWaitHandleRights is gone. Is there a way to open an existing named event with specific rights in .NET Core?

Comment: It's not there because the Core team forgot to include it.  There's an [issue saying this on the Core website](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/2117).  There's also a suggested workaround for opening a Mutex with MutexRights, which they also forgot, although not one for your scenario.  The issue has been given low priority because there are workarounds.  Writing your own version as a workaround involves calling Kernel32 functions on Windows (is this on Windows?), which you could work out by decompiling the Framework code.

Comment: Hopefully it will be in .NET 5.0 or 5.1.  I don't like the "there's a workaround" excuse because you can say that about tons classes and method that are really just wrappers for Windows API functions.

Answer (score 1):

As of .NET 6, the [Windows Compatibility Pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/windows-compat-pack) provides an [`EventWaitHandleAcl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.eventwaithandleacl) Class with an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.eventwaithandleacl.openexisting) of the same overload.